# is it possible to use SSL_set_fd() with pipe?

Tags: c++, openssl

I use ssl server. I want to use pipe as a file descriptor in SSL_set_fd.

My goal is to write ssl-packets throught pipe to ssl-server. Code:

```
// First thread
SSL * ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
int descriptors[2];
int res = pipe( descriptors );
if ( res == -1 ){ 
    throw std::runtime_error( "pipe error" );
}
res = SSL_set_rfd(ssl, descriptors[0]);
if ( res != 1 ){
    throw std::runtime_error("SSL_set_rfd");
} 
// Here the thread will stop for waiting ssl-hello
res = SSL_accept( ssl );



// In the second thread I am going to write ssl-packets to server: 
struct pollfd fds[1];
fds[0].fd = descriptors[1];    
fds[0].events = POLLOUT;
 
std::vector <unsigned char> sslPacket = waitAndPop();
            
int rc = poll( fds, 1, 10000 );
if ( rc < 0 ){
    throw std::runtime_error("poll error");
}           
if ( rc == 0 ){
    throw std::runtime_error("timeout");
}
 
if ( fds[0].revents & POLLOUT ){
    fds[0].revents = 0;
    rc = send( descriptors[1], sslPacket.data(), sslPacket.size(), 0 );
}
```

The problem is that send() always return errno 38 which means "Function not implemented". Am I doing something wrong? Is it possible to set pipe as file descriptor for ssl?

macOS 10.15.4, Xcode 11.5, OpenSSL 1.1.1

I read this docs:
1.https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html
2.https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/SSL_set_fd.html
3.https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/pipe.2.html

Comment: What version of OpenSSL?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings, openssl 1.1.1

Comment: _"The problem is that send() always return errno 38 which means "Function not implemented"_ Does this not suggest that the problem is with `send()`, not with the other functions you use?

Comment: Do you really mean that it "returns" errno 38? `send()` does not return an errno. [It returns the number of bytes sent, or -1 for error](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/send.2.html). If there's an error, you check the `errno` global variable to find out why. Unfortunately you do not show your working in your question so I can only guess...

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings, send() works perfect with socket. I have error only then I change it to pipe.  You are right - send() return -1, errno = 38.

Comment: OpenSSL's older SSL API does its own I/O internally and that works only with socket descriptors, not files, pipes, etc.  If you want to do your own I/O, use OpenSSL's newer BIO API instead, then you can read/write data using whatever you want. You would just be pushing data into the BIO's engine and getting data back out of it, all of the I/O would be your responsibility to handle.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `send` with a pipe. You can use `write` with a pipe. `send` is only for sockets.

Comment: Shame `ENOTSOCK` wasn't given really

Answer (score 0):

While **BIO_new_bio_pair** seems like a better way - you can still fake pipe with sockets.
Here is example how to create socket pair: https://github.com/KxSystems/kafka/blob/master/socketpair.c

It's for Windows, but can easily be ported to any system with POSIX sockets